# Deciding if random variables are consecutive in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and am using JavaScript to program a simple poker dice game with
three randomly rolled die. The best possible hand is a straight ie 3, 4, 5. The problem I'm
having is coding the method of deciding whether the three die are consecutive. At the moment the best I have come up with is:

```
if ((die3 === die2 + 1 && die2 === die1 + 1) || 
    (die3 === die1 + 1 && die1 === die2 + 1) || 
    (die2 === die3 + 1 && die3 === die1 + 1) || 
    (die2 === die1 + 1 && die1 === die3 + 1) || 
    (die1 === die3 + 1 && die3 === die2 + 1) || 
    (die1 === die2 + 1 && die2 === die3 + 1))
```

This works, but seems very inelegant and would be a nightmare to scale up if I were to try to use more than three dice.

Any help with an alternative method would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you work with an array. Either rearrange your code to use `die[0]` instead of `die1`, `die[1]` for `die2`, etc.

Once you have an array, you can do things like `.sort()` it, and search it iteratively to find the numbers you're looking for.

For instance, after sorting numbers will be in order, so you just need to test for:

```
if( die[1] == die[0]+1 && die[2] == die[1]+1)
```

Comment: And to make this more general: You could easily write a function with loop or recursion that checks the difference between each element and the next one.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of sorting an array is close to correct that people are doing; however, they are forgetting that there should not be any duplicates in that array.  **You should first sort them and then look for duplicates.**  Assume `dice` is an array of your dice values.

```
// Assumes at least two dice
function isStraight(dice) {
  dice.sort();
  var duplicates = false;
  for(var index = 0; index < dice.length - 1; index++) {
    if(dice[index] == dice[index + 1]) {
      duplicates = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return !duplicates && (dice[dice.length - 1] - dice[0] == dice.length - 1);
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle with three simple tests](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWXL6/1/) (non exhaustive).

If you actually use this method, you should make a copy of the `dice` array before sorting it.  Unless you don't care if the dice array is changed.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution for 2 or more numbers:

```
    var ar = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5 and so on];  
    ar.sort();  

    var i = 1, first = ar[0];
    while (ar[i] === (first + i)) i++;

    if (i === ar.length) // consecutive
```

[test](http://jsbin.com/opoler/3/watch) it here!

Comment: Seems to work fine with 3 dice, but won't work with 4 or an even number of dice: `[2,2,4,4]`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Improved for any number of dices.

Comment: @user1907766 did you have a look?